# Guava Service stop while state is STARTING

Tags: java, service, guava

We have a couple of services which take a while to start (1-2min). During this process someone might request a forced shutdown of the service (ie transition `STARTING -> STOPPING`). Looking at the source of [AbstractService](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractService.html) class I see there is no call to `doStop()`  when the current state `STARTING` or `NEW` which means the underlying class is not notified when a stop request was received.

```java
  switch (snapshot.state) {
    case NEW:
      snapshot = new StateSnapshot(State.TERMINATED);
      terminated(State.NEW);
      break;
    case STARTING:
      snapshot = new StateSnapshot(State.STARTING, true, null);
      stopping(State.STARTING);
      break;
    case RUNNING:
      snapshot = new StateSnapshot(State.STOPPING);
      stopping(State.RUNNING);
      doStop();
      break;
    case STOPPING:
    case TERMINATED:
    case FAILED:
      // do nothing
      break;
    default:
      throw new AssertionError("Unexpected state: " + snapshot.state);
  }
```

Since I need to perform some cleanup regardless of the state, is there a way to get notified about a shutdown ? Is it a good idea to use [Service.Listener](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Service.Listener.html) within the subclass ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no call to `doStop` when the state is `NEW` or `STARTING` because you don't have to stop a service that never started.  That does not mean that the underlying class is not notified when a stop request is received.  Referring to [the source for `stop()`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/search?q=AbstractService&origq=AbstractService&btnG=Search+Trunk), if the state is `NEW`, `terminated` is called, which queues up listeners to have their `terminated` methods invoked.  Similarly if the state is `STARTING`, `stopping` is called, which queues up listeners to have their `stopping` methods invoked.  Then the `finally` block in `stop` calls `executeListeners` to execute any queued up `Listener`s.

So in short, yes it is a good idea to use a `Service.Listener`.  Be sure to add the `Listener` to the `Service` before you start it so you don't miss notifications of any state transitions.  The `failed`, `stopping`, and `terminated` methods all get the `Service.State` that the `Service` was in passed to them, so you can have your cleanup code in your `Listener`s `terminated` method for the normal case (where the `Service` gets `RUNNING`), inside an `if (from == STARTING)` block in your `stopping` method for the case you described where you want to force a shutdown during start up, and in your `failed` method for exceptional cases.

Comment: Whoops.  As soon as I posted that, I realized you said the underlying class isn't notified because `doStop` isn't called.  So I guess my answer could basically be just the second paragraph of my answer.  :-)

Comment: Yeah, but I figured there's still some useful info in there.